# Integers are not adding / subtracting

Tags: powershell, integer

I am reading some data from a Database and the value in question is a Date and Time Stamp.

To keep things short the Data is similar to this. 
7/24/2015 16:13:58

I then extract the Date only like this.

```
$ScanDate = $($Row[3]).ToString()
        [String]$Scan = $ScanDate.SubString(0,10)
```

I then split the $ScanDate into an Array

$Scan.Split('/')

Then i change the Value to an Integer for each Day, Month and Year

```
[int]$ScanMonth = $Scan[0]
[int]$ScanDay = $Scan[1]
[int]$ScanYear = $Scan[2]
```

Check they are Integers..

```
$ScanDay.GetType()
$ScanYear.GetType()
$ScanMonth.GetType()
```

Returns..

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Int32                                    System.ValueType
True     True     Int32                                    System.ValueType
True     True     Int32                                    System.ValueType
```

The issue is when i try and add and subtract those Integers, I am getting the wrong result?

```
$Total = [int]$ScanDay + [int]$ScanMonth
Write-Host $Total
```

So the values 24 + 7 come out as 102 not 31.

What am i missing? Any help appreciated :)

**Updated**

Ok so i wanted to add the final compare code..After being told the Database value was interpreted by powershell as a Datetime I could do everything like this.

```
$Date = Get-Date
$Date = $Date.ToUniversalTime()

$DayDifference = New-TimeSpan -Start $Date -End $Row[3]
if ($DayDifference.TotalDays -gt 5) { 'Do Something' }
```

Comment: `$Scan` is a `[String]`, so `$Scan[0]` is a `[Char]`. `[Char]` casted to `[int]` produce it codepoint. So `$ScanMonth` is codepoint of `7` 55, and `$ScanDay` is codepoint of `/` 47. 55+47=102.

Comment: Ahh so the values are still not true numbers? How can i make them numbers instead of codepoints?

Comment: They are numbers but `$scan.split('/');` doesn't do much. try `$scan = $scan.split('/');`

Comment: Still getting codepoint values.

Comment: BTW What type of `$Row[3]`? Is not it `[datetime]` already? You can just use `.Day` and `.Month` in that case.

Comment: Funny you should say that as all i am trying to do is compare todays date with the scandate. But because the scandate is a string from a database I did not think powershell would recognise it as a date. The goal is if the scandate is more than 5 days previous to todays date - do something. I was trying to subtract 5 from the value $ScanDay

Comment: Are value from database really a `string` not a `datetime` (try `$Row[3].GetType()`)?

Comment: Ah you are right it picks it up as Datetime..  so now a simple compare will do the trick.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scan = "7/24/2015 16:13:58"
$scan = $scan.Split('/');
[int]$ScanMonth = $Scan[0]
[int]$ScanDay = $Scan[1]
[int]$ScanYear = ($Scan[2].Split())[0]

$Total = [int]$ScanDay + [int]$ScanMonth
Write-Host $Total
```

Then you'll get 31.. Although I still think you should be using DateTime object

*Update*
: An easier way to solve your actual problem:

```
$scan = "7/24/2015 16:13:58"
$scanDate = [DateTime]$scan
$date = (get-date).addDays(-5)
if($date -lt $scanDate) {'Do Something'}
```

Comment: Not sure how to split points on here but the help was greatly appreciated. Also going long way round i learnt even more. Thanks!